# UIPageControl Not Updating Even the value changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

So I have **MainViewController** with a **ContainerView** embedded with a `PageViewController` this PageViewController have 2 pages, I've added a PageControl on top of the containerView, However trying to update the pages with the method

```
 PageControl.currentPage = status.page
```

is not working. Plus I've printed the value initially and after swiping, the value of the currentpage changes, but the UI is not updating.

Here's what I've done so far.

**MainViewController**

```
   struct status {
    static var viewstat = ""
    static var bottomContainerHeightCon: CGFloat!
    static var containerHeightCon: CGFloat!
    static var bhbefore: CGFloat!
    static var chbefore: CGFloat!
    static var buttonstat = "false"
    static var page: Int = 0
}
   @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }


  func changePage() {

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}


   func configurePageControl() {
    // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
    self.pageControl.currentPage = status.page
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black   
}
```

**PageViewController**

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self
     configurePageControl()
    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionsPage");
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NeedPaymentPage");
    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)


}


 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {


    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
    self.pageControl.currentPage = pages.index(of: pageContentViewController)!


  let currentIndex = pages.index(of: previousViewControllers.first!)!
  NeedDetailsController.status.page = currentIndex
    NeedController.changePage()


}
```

Comment: @SharadChauhan I believe i've added it into the pageviewcontroller.

Comment: @SharadChauhan What do you mean add that too? Yes the pageView is working perfectly the pageControl is only the problem.

Comment: @SharadChauhan Thats the MainViewController, I just named it here MainViewController so it will be more easier to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these line :

```
NeedDetailsController.status.page = currentIndex
NeedController.changePage()
```

You can't set values like this. Try adding this if block in `didFinishAnimating` method and then access properties using `parentController`.

```
if let parentController = self.parent as? NeedDetailsController {
    print("didFinishAnimating is getting called.")
}
```